# How can I find the elements of array 2 that correspond to the false elements in array 1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm updating a model through a `has_many` relationship and I'm trying to figure out which of the elements have not updated properly so that I can throw a sensible exception:

```
foos_updated = foos.collect do |foo|
  foo.update_attributes({:attribute => update})
end
```

If `foos_updated.count(true) == foos.count`, I know that all of the updates went through. But, if some of the foos were not updated, I'll have `false` elements in the `food_updated` array.

What's the best way to map the false elements in `foos_updated` to the corresponding element in `foos`?

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a slightly different approach :

```
 rejected = foos.reject{ |foo| foo.update_attributes(attribute: update) }

 if rejected.any?
   # do something
 end
```

or maybe a less convoluted, more explicit way :

```
errors = []
foos.each do |foo|
  foo.update_attribute(attribute: update)
  errors << foo if foo.errors.any? 
end
```

in fact, with AR objects you might as well just do this :

```
foos.each{ |foo| foo.update_attributes(attribute: update) }
rejected = foos.select{ |foo| foo.errors.any? }
```

depending on the context, if failure is very unlikely and you just want to *throw a sensible exception*, just do this :

```
foos.each do |foo|
  begin
    foo.update_attribute!(attribute: update) # notice the bang!
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
    # do something (store message, etc.) and / or re-raise
  end
end
```

Comment: These are all examples I'd feel comfortable seeing in live code, but I think the `foos.select { |foo| foo.errors.any? }` is the cleanest, most expressive approach here

Comment: Agreed. The only downside is that you have to iterate twice instead of once, but no big deal, and ruby is all about expressiveness :)